# do something at unsuccessful jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, themoviedb-api

My ajax request is hitting an api with rate limits.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.themoviedb.org/xxx",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    dataObj : index,
    success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log('success');
    }
    ,error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

I would like to know when I hit the rate limit.

But for the requests showing this in the console :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (OK)

I don't see 'success' or 'error'.
It's like success and error are not executed.

Is there a way to popup and alert e.g. ?

I tried `complete` but it does not work either.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find documentation for `dataObj` but removing it seemed to make the query run properly.

If you get rid of it the `error` callback gets executed and you will be able to see `error` in the console.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.themoviedb.org/xxx",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log('success');
    }
    ,error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

edit:
turns out what you actually want to change is the datatype. Unless you are explicitly also passing a callback you should tell jQuery that you are getting `json` and not `jsonp` back.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.themoviedb.org/xxx",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    dataObj: index,
    success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log('success');
    }
    ,error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid `dataObj` is essential. In case of success I'm using it like this : `window.data[this.dataObj].xxx = response.xxx;` cf. answer in previous questions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646946/fetch-movie-data-from-apis-in-javascript

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation of it? As far as I can tell dataobj is just not a valid property for the ajax function.

Comment: does it work when you set the `dataType`  to `json` instead of `jsonp` as mentioned in my edit?

Comment: also where does the `index` come from that you are using as the `dataObj` parameter? Can you show the surrounding code?

Comment: jsonp to json did the trick, `error` and `statusCode` are working. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery statusCode object in the settings, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.themoviedb.org/xxx",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    dataObj : index,
    success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error');
    },
    statusCode: {
      429: function() {
        alert( "Exceeded request limit." );
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: 429 is IIRC if the API you're calling block because you e.g. exceed the limit of requests in which case you get back xhr.status = 0 and not 429.

Comment: is it possible to access the response object in the function for the `429` status code?